# Combine multiple datasets to single dataset without using unionAll function in Apache Spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am having my datasets as follows

```
  Dataset 1:

+----------+--------------------+---------+---+
|      Time|             address|     Date|value|sample
+----------+--------------------+---------+---+------+
|8:00:00 AM| AAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|12/9/2014|  1  |0    |
|8:31:27 AM| AAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|12/9/2014|  1  |0    |
+----------+--------------------+---------+---+------+

Dataset 2:


|       Time|            Location|     Date|sample|value
+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+------+
| 8:45:00 AM| AAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|12/9/2016|     5 | 0    |
| 9:15:00 AM| AAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|12/9/2016|     5 | 0    |
+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+------+
```

I am using the following unionAll() function to combine both ds1  and ds2,

```
Dataset<Row> joined = dataset1.unionAll(dataset2).distinct();
```

Is there any better way to combine this ds1 and ds2, Since unionAll() function is deprecated in Spark 2.x.?

Comment: just use `union()`, it will drop duplicate records by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union()` to combine the two dataframes/datasets

```
df1.union(df2)
```

Output:

```
+----------+------------------+---------+-----+------+
|      Time|           address|     Date|value|sample|
+----------+------------------+---------+-----+------+
|8:00:00 AM|AAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|12/9/2014|    1|     0|
|8:31:27 AM|AAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|12/9/2014|    1|     0|
|8:45:00 AM|AAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|12/9/2016|    5|     0|
|9:15:00 AM|AAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|12/9/2016|    5|     0|
+----------+------------------+---------+-----+------+
```

It also removes the duplicates rows

Hope this helps!

Comment: @mtoto 
` +----------+------------------+---------+-----+------+------+--------+
|      Time|           address|                    Date  |value|sample|
+----------+------------------+---------+-----+------+
|8:00:00 AM|AAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|12/9/2014|    0|     1|
|8:31:27 AM|AAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|12/9/2014|    0|     1|
|8:45:00 AM|AAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|12/9/2016|    5|     0|
|9:15:00 AM|AAbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|12/9/2016|    5|     0|
+----------+------------------+---------+-----+------+------+--------+ `
joined dataset output has both value and sample columns values in the value column itself.